# Some questions about Java Generics

Tags: java, generics, type-mismatch

Let's say I have the following interface and implementing class:

```
interface Foo<FooType extends Foo<FooType>> {
    FooType copy();
}

class Bar implements Foo<Bar> {
    public Bar copy() {
        return new Bar();
    }       
}
```

If I try to do this:

```
public <FooType extends Foo<FooType>> FooType getFoo() {
    return new Bar();
}
```

I get the compile error "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Bar to FooType". **Why?**

I can "fix" this by rewriting the function like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <FooType extends Foo<FooType>> FooType getFoo() {
    return (FooType) new Bar();
}
```

But let's say I have a function like this:

```
public <FooType extends Foo<FooType>> void printFoo(FooType foo) {
    System.out.println(foo.toString());
}
```

If I try to do this:

```
printFoo(getFoo());
```

I get the following compile error:

```
Bound mismatch: The generic method printFoo(FooType) is not applicable 
for the arguments (Foo<Foo<FooType>>). The inferred type Foo<Foo<FooType>> 
is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <FooType extends Foo<FooType>>
```

**WAT?** The return type of getFoo() is literally identical to the argument type of printFoo()!

Are these bugs or am I missing something?

Comment: In case someone doesn't know what WAT is: https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat :)

Comment: Is the compiler error on doGetFoo because Bar is a non generic and FooType is a generic parameter?

Comment: You should rewrite to use a single-letter name for the generic type. It is hard to read code written against this convention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! Thanks to meriton who answered this version of the question:

[How to replace run-time instanceof check with compile-time generics validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636312/how-to-replace-run-time-instanceof-check-with-compile-time-generics-validation)

I need to baby-step the compiler through the `printFoo(getFoo())`-part by doing this:

```
public <FooType extends Foo<FooType>> void doPrint() {
    FooType foo = getFoo();
    printFoo(foo);
}
```

and instead call `doPrint()` then.

Then everything works fine.

So, I guess even though the "Why?" in the middle may have been my lack of understanding (thanks to Bhesh for clearing up that part), the "WAT?" at the end was justified since this really should just work... For example, it's not OK, for some reason, to inline the variable definition for "foo" in the code above...

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `FooType` could be anything not just `Bar`. You can return an instance of `FooType`.

e.g. if you have `class NotBar implements Foo<NotBar> {` then

```
 obj.<NotBar>getFoo();
```

Now the actual argument for `FooType` is `NotBar`.

Comment: Right, but shouldn't it pick what it is? Isn't that the point of generic functions?

Comment: Ahhhh! Gotcha!!! The type of FooType is determined by the context in which I USE the function, not by what I return! Makes sense...

Comment: But what's the problem with the invocation printFoo(getFoo())? Is it that it has no true way to determine the generic type to use and therefore comes up with something random?

Comment: If you tried `printFoo(this.<Bar>getFoo())` I would probably work as you have locked downt the type coming out of `getFoo`.

Comment: @Markus: `FooType` parameter in the two separate methods are not the same. You already saw that, one could return `NotBar` other could expect `NotBar`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this, with the method that you declare:

```
public <FooType extends Foo<FooType>> FooType doGetFoo()
```

This is a generic method that states that I should get back the type of the generic that I specify. For example, if I have a call `Bat` that extends `Foo<Bat>` and I call `instance.<Bat>doGetFoo()` it should return an instance of `Bat` instead it is hard-coded to return an instance of `Bar` with is not necessarily an instance of the class specified in the generic. If you remove the generic as below you should be fine:

```
public Foo<?> doGetFoo(){
    return new Bar();
}
```